# How to make Azure Rules Engine make all incoming uri paths lowercase?

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, rule-engine, azure-cdn

Currently I have tried a few different combinations.
Essentially what I need to do this this:
[www.mydomain.com/mYpaTh](http://www.mydomain.com/mYpaTh) needs to rewrite to: [www.mydomain.com/mypath](http://www.mydomain.com/mypath) but it needs to do a toLowerCase for every incoming uri, essentially making the uris case insensitive. The method cannot effect query parameters or file extensions.

This needs to be done as a wildcard, not as a specific case, most examples found online have it for only one scenario, to set up as a basic url rewrite. I need it to be done as follows:

Incoming uri contains /[A-Z] then rewrite to /[a-z] - not sure if azure actually allows this. WIld cards don't seem to work for the standard subscription, but not sure if someone has made it work in some way. I was able to get this to work in AWS cloudfront using basic javascript toLowerCase method.

For example:
[Azure CDN Rules Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUeat.png)

Comment: An update on this, currently this is not supported by the standard azure cdn. It's only supported by Verizon Premium. (kind of lame, since aws supports this through a cloudfront function).